# django redirect user to the post after creating it

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i want to redirect the user to the post after creating it with django forms

in models.py

```
class Text(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    document = models.TextField(max_length=None, null=True)
    requirements = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(null=True)

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

in my view.py

```
    if request.method == "POST":   
        form = TextForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated:
            user = request.user
            text = form.save(commit=False)
            author = User.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
            text.author = author
            form.save()
            form = TextForm()

    context = {'form': form, 'text': text}

    return render(request, 'main/text.html', context)
```

in my forms.py

```
class TextForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Text
        fields = ['title','document','requirements','deadline']
        widgets = {
            'title' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Title','class':'form-control m-2 mb-4 pb-2'}),
            'deadline' : forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Deadline','type':'date','class':'form-control m-2 pt-2',
            'id':'opendate'}),
            'requirements' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':ps_note,'class':'form-control col m-2','rows':'3'}),
            'document' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':ps_text,'class':'form-control'}),

        }
```

in my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('text/<str:pk>', views.text, name="text"),
    path('signin/', views.signin, name="signin"),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name="signup"),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name="logout"),
]
```

i had to add this so stackoverflow accepts my question because it said that it's mostly code even after saying all the details i think

Comment: Can you add the urls.py?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu i added it

Comment: IMHO, better to split the list view and detail view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone is looking for something similar,
after doing some research i was able to solve it on my own here is what i did:

```
if request.method == "POST":   
    text_form = TextForm(request.POST)
    if text_form.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
        text = text_form.save(commit=False)
        author = User.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
        text.author = author
        text_form.save()
        text_form = TextForm()
          # this to select the id of the model object
        pk = text.id
        return redirect("text",pk)
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you must use " commit "

```
form.save(commit=True)
```

check this answer

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598465/django-redirect-to-detail-view-after-creation)

Answer (score 0):

```
def text(request, pk):

    form = TextForm()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TextForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            text = form.save(commit=False)
            text = Text.objects.get(id=pk)
            text.save()
            return redirect('text')
    else:
        text = Text.objects.get(id=pk)

    context = {'form': form, 'text': text}

    return render(request, 'main/text.html', context)
```

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't you change "name" to "pk" in your urls.py?

Comment: i don't think so , it works fine when i try to enter each post , my problem is with redirect to the post that's been created